# snakemake rule won't run the complete command

Tags: snakemake

I am working on this snakemake pipeline where the last rule looks like this:

```
rule RunCodeml:
input:
                '{ProjectFolder}/{Fastas}/codeml.ctl'
        output:
                '{ProjectFolder}/{Fastas}/codeml.out'
        shell:
                'codeml {input}'
```

This rule does not run and the error seems to be that the program codeml can't find the .ctl file because it looks for an incomplete path: '/work_beegfs/sunam133/Anas_plasmids/Phylo_chromosome/Acinet_only/Klebs_Esc_SCUG/cluster_536/co'
although the command seems correct:

```
shell:
        codeml /work_beegfs/sunam133/Anas_plasmids/Phylo_chromosome/Acinet_only/Klebs_Esc_SCUG/cluster_536/codeml.ctl
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)'
```

And here the output from running with -p option:

```
error when opening file /work_beegfs/sunam133/Anas_plasmids/Phylo_chromosome/Acinet_only/Klebs_Esc_SCUG/cluster_1083/co
tell me the full path-name of the file? Can't find the file.  I give up.
```

I find this behavior very strange and I can't figure out what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!
D.

Comment: Can you edit your post the add the output from running snakemake with `-p` option like `snakemake -p [your-other-options]`?

Comment: Sure. Now it's there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was not snakemake but the program I am calling (codeml), which is restricted in the length of the string given as path to the control file.